# How can I tell if my SSH keys are ed25519?

Tags: ssh, openssh

How can I tell if my existing SSH keys are ed25519?

```
$ ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
4096 SHA256:L3oWmCPI5Iz492hRwiNV2oldgxW6jiEkf8CQ4NDkggQ user@host (RSA)
$ ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
4096 SHA256:L3oWmCPI5Iz492hRwiNV2oldgxW6jiEkf8CQ4NDkggQ user@host (RSA)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
ssh-keygen -vvv -l -f filespec
```

Look at the output, eg

```
~/.ssh % ssh-keygen -l -vvv -f foo.pub | head -2 | tail -1
+---[RSA 2048]----+
```

Note that this is a 2048 bit RSA key.

Comment: That won't tell you if it's ed25519, will it?

Comment: What did it show for your ed25519 key?

Comment: Obviously I put this answer here to help you, because I think it does what you ask which is tell you if your ssh key is an ed25519. You seem to believe otherwise and I'm curious why.

Comment: It does work.  Thanks.  Keys I thought were ed25519 were actually not.

Comment: I used this with a key I know to be ed25519 and the top line of output was:

`+--[ED25519 256]--+`